# Flutter - Strange behaviour for bottomNavigationBar and PageView

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a parent widget and 3 children widgets managed by bottomNavigationBar and PageView together.

Data entered in Page 1 children widget will be sent to Page 2.

I have a method **onTapped** in Parent widget, will update the name to "John" entered in Page1 and then display in Page2.

Assuming if I entered the name "Jane" in Page1 and when I clicked Page2 on the bottomNavigationBar, the method onTapped will update the name to Page2 immediately (John is displayed). The problem is if I were to swipe from Page1 to Page2. The name on Page 2 is still "Jane". If I swipe to Page 3 then back to Page 2 or Page 1 to Page 2 another time, the name is then updated to "John".

The bottomNavigationBar's "onTap:" and PageView's "onPageChanged:" both using the same method **onTapped**.

[image: pageview]

I was expecting both page swipe or click on the navigationbar will produce the same result.

Comment: It seems like PageView onPageChanged is called only after viewport changes as mentioned here: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/PageView/onPageChanged.html

It works differently from bottomNavigationBar: Called when one of the items is tapped.

Is there a way to run the method using PageView before viewport changes?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comment, PageView onPageChanged is called only after viewport changes as mentioned here: docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/PageView/onPageChanged.html It works differently from bottomNavigationBar: Called when one of the items is tapped.

To call the method before 2nd page: add Listener to the pageController. It solved my problem.